# What is the better and more precise way to train a Name Finder model in OpenNLP, NameFinderME or TokenNameFinderTrainer?

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition, opennlp, semantic-search

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to train a Name Finder model in OpenNLP to recognize specific entities in text. I've come across two different approaches for training the model, using NameFinderME or TokenNameFinderTrainer.

I would like to know which of these approaches is better and more precise for training the model. Are there any advantages or disadvantages to using one over the other? What are the differences in the output of the trained model when using these two approaches?

Additionally, I would appreciate any tips or best practices for training a Name Finder model in OpenNLP.

Thank you for your help!